# Is there a way to import / export Syntax Coloring in Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, editor, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to import / export Syntax Coloring in Flash Builder? If not how hard would it be to build?

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible, you can import preferences or export them, this will give you the option to import other people's preferences and make your flash builder look like textmate or something else.

Answer (score 1):

This eclipse plugin will do the job.
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/